# Getting AttributeError: 'TestInventorySellStock' object has no attribute 'balance_inventory' while testing below pytest framework

Tags: python, testing, pytest

I am trying to test a framework containing 3 classes as shown below. While running the test using pytest, i am getting **'AttributeError: 'TestInventorySellStock' object has no attribute 'balance_inventory''** as shown below. **'balance_inventory'** has been defined in 2nd class **'MobileInventory'**, but somehow i am not able to reference it into 3rd class **'TestInventorySellStock'**. Can someone please help in pointing where i am doing wrong?

P.S: Apologies in advance if i missed to add any info. Please let me know incase if i need to add any other details.

**1st Class:**

```
class InsufficientException(Exception):
    pass
```

**2nd class:**

```
class MobileInventory:
    def __init__(self, inventory=None):
        if inventory is None:
            self.balance_inventory = {}
        else:
            if not isinstance(inventory, dict):
                raise TypeError("Input inventory must be a dictionary")
            for model in inventory:
                if not isinstance(model, str):
                    raise ValueError("Mobile model name must be a string")
                if not isinstance(inventory[model], int) or inventory[model] < 0:
                    raise ValueError("No. of mobiles must be a positive integer")
            self.balance_inventory = inventory

    def sell_stock(self, requested_stock):
        if not isinstance(requested_stock, dict):
            raise TypeError("Requested stock must be a dictionary")
        for model in requested_stock:
            if not isinstance(model, str):
                raise ValueError("Mobile model name must be a string")
            if not isinstance(requested_stock[model], int) or requested_stock[model] < 0:
                raise ValueError("No. of mobiles must be a positive integer")
            if model not in self.balance_inventory:
                raise InsufficientException("No Stock. New Model Request")
            if requested_stock[model] > self.balance_inventory[model]:
                raise InsufficientException("Insufficient Stock")
            self.balance_inventory[model] -= requested_stock[model]
```

**3rd Class:**

```
class TestInventorySellStock:
    
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        cls.inventory = MobileInventory({'iPhone Model A': 50, 'Xiaomi Model B': 2000, 'Nokia Model C': 10, 'Sony Model D': 1})

    def test_sell_stock_as_dict(self):
        self.inventory.sell_stock({'iPhone Model A': 2, 'Xiaomi Model B': 20, 'Sony Model D': 1})
        assert self.inventory.balance_inventory == {'iPhone Model A': 48, 'Xiaomi Model B': 1980, 'Nokia Model C': 10,
                                                'Sony Model D': 0}

    def test_sell_stock_with_float_values(self):
        with pytest.raises(ValueError) as e:
            MobileInventory.sell_stock(self, {'iPhone Model A': 2.5, 'Xiaomi Model B': 3.1, 'Nokia Model C': 4})
        assert str(e.value) == 'No. of mobiles must be a positive integer'

    def test_sell_stock_of_nonexisting_model(self):
        with pytest.raises(InsufficientException) as e:
            MobileInventory.sell_stock(self, {'iPhone Model B': 2, 'Xiaomi Model B': 5})
        assert str(e.value) == 'No Stock. New Model Request'

    def test_sell_stock_of_insufficient_stock(self):
        with pytest.raises(InsufficientException) as e:
            MobileInventory.sell_stock(self, {'iPhone Model A': 2, 'Xiaomi Model B': 5, 'Nokia Model C': 15})
        assert str(e.value) == 'Insufficient Stock'
```

**Complete Error details:**

[image: Complete Error details:]

Comment: Looks like a tutorial on classes and OOP could help. `MobileInventory.sell_stock(self, ...)` passes `self`, which is of type `TestInventorySellStock` (!), which `MobileInventory.sell_stock` will treat as an object of (possibly a subtype of) `MobileInventory`.

Comment: @ForceBru Hi. Thanks for replying. I have done the same in above code. Even though i have defined 'balance_inventory' in 'MobileInventory' class, it is not able to refer to that when used in another class 'TestInventorySellStock'. Are you trying to explain something other than that? If so, can you please share more details?

Comment: basically, you should use `self.inventory` in `TestInventorySellStock`. You're already using it in `test_sell_stock_as_dict`, so why did you switch to `MobileInventory.sell_stock` in other methods?

Comment: @ForceBru It worked after i used 'self.inventory.sell_stock' instead of 'MobileInventory.sell_stock'. I am amazed to know how such a small change had fixed an entire framework. Thanks a lot for pointing it out.

Answer (score -1):

As @ForceBru suggested above in the comments, the code worked after i replaced 'MobileInventory' with 'self.inventory' in both 2nd & 3rd class. This should be the way how classes are handled in Python. More knowledge on OOP's would be required to solve such problems.